# verdaccio authenticating against ldap

Tags: npm, ldap

I am experiencing errors when trying to setup verdaccio to authenticate against active directory.I get the following error on the backend which is a centos 7 aws machine and my client machine is in corporate office as well as the AD server (VPN connected):

my steps to recreate:

```
npm set registry https://npm.mydomain.io
npm adduser --registry https://npm.mydomain.io



http  <-- 409, user: undefined, req: 'PUT /-/user/org.couchdb.user:andrewm', error: registration is disabled
0|verdacci |  http  <-- 200, user: undefined, req: 'GET /-/user/org.couchdb.user:andrewm?write=true', bytes: 0/106
0|verdacci |  warn  --- LDAP error { message: '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1\u0000',
0|verdacci |   name: 'InvalidCredentialsError',
0|verdacci |   stack: 'InvalidCredentialsError: InvalidCredentialsError\n    at messageCallback (/usr/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1419:45)\n    at Parser.onMessage (/usr/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1089:14)\n    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at Parser.emit (events.js:191:7)\n    at Parser.write (/usr/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/messages/parser.js:111:8)\n    at TLSSocket.onData (/usr/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1076:22)\n    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:191:7)\n    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)\n    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)',
0|verdacci |   code: 49,
0|verdacci |   signal: undefined }
0|verdacci |  http  <-- 409, user: undefined, req: 'PUT /-/user/org.couchdb.user:andrewm/-rev/undefined', error: registration is disabled
```

and I get the following error on the client machine which is window 7

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "adduser" "--registry" "https://npm.aud"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code E409

npm ERR! registration is disabled : -/user/org.couchdb.user:andrewm/-rev/undefined
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\andrewm\npm-debug.log
```

npm config list

```
; cli configs
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/4.2.0 node/v7.10.0 linux x64"

; userconfig /home/ec2-user/.npmrc
http-proxy = null
https-proxy = null
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl = false

; globalconfig /usr/etc/npmrc
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"

; node bin location = /usr/bin/node
; cwd = /home/ec2-user
; HOME = /home/ec2-user
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

My config file is below

```
storage: ./storage

###########
auth:
  ldap:
    type: ldap
    groupNameAttribute: 'admin'
    client_options:
      url: "ldaps://tordc1"
      adminDn: "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
      adminPassword: "P@@k3"
      searchBase: "ou=Aud Corp,dc=toronto,dc=aud"
      searchFilter: "(uid={{admin}})"
      cache: False
      searchAttributes:
        - "*"
        - memberOf
      tlsOptions:
        rejectUnauthorized: False
##########


# a list of other known repositories we can talk to
uplinks:
  npmjs:
    url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
###########

packages:
  # uncomment this for packages with "local-" prefix to be available
  # for admin only, it's a recommended way of handling private packages
   'av-*':
      allow_access: $all
      allow_publish: $all

   '*':
      allow_access: $all
      allow_publish: $all
      proxy: npmjs

   '@*/*':
      allow_access: $all
      allow_publish: $authenticated
      proxy: npmjs


https:
  key: /home/ec2-user/verdaccio/verdaccio-keynew.pem
  cert: /home/ec2-user/verdaccio/verdaccio-certnew.pem
  ca: /home/ec2-user/verdaccio/server.ca


# log settings
logs:
  - {type: stdout, format: pretty, level: http}
  #- {type: file, path: verdaccio.log, level: info}

listen:
- https://devnpm:4873
max_body_size: 300mb
```

Could I get some assistance on resolving my issue pleaseÉ

Thank you

Comment: can anyone assist?

Comment: `error: registration is disabled` clearly means your auth plugin is not working. You should report an issue here https://github.com/Alexandre-io/verdaccio-ldap